# Convert 2 bytes digits eg.' ０','１' to single byte digits eg. '0','1' in a string using php

Tags: php, byte

I am working on a project where a user can search a query from search box in Japanese.
Japanese language have digits in 2 bytes eg.**('０', '１', '２', '３', '４', '５', '６', '７', '８', '９')** unlike in 
English **('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9').** The digits in the data to be searched is in single byte format but while searching the user may accidentally type digits with 2 bytes (as Japanese typing) and hence the query returns nothing.
I want to a standard solution on this problem to prevent this problem situation. I want some sort of function to find and replace the 2 bytes digits to single byte digit before executing the query.
In short I want to translate this **'苯ぎょ氨ソ椥 １０'** to **'苯ぎょ氨ソ椥 10'**

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [mb_convert_kana()](http://php.net/mb_convert_kana)

```
$str =  '苯ぎょ氨ソ椥 １０';
$str = mb_convert_kana($str, "KVa", 'UTF-8');
echo $str;
```

Output

> 苯ぎょ氨ソ椥 10